# Hiding a tooltip via the tooltip-is-open attribute doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I want to display a clickable element (a font awesome icon) that copies some data into the clipboard. When a click event occurs I also want to display a tooltip which should disappear once the cursor left (mouseleave) the element.

This element is a directive as I use it several times in my application.

Copying the data is not an issue at all, displaying the tooltip neither. However, it doesn't disappear when the mouse leaves the font awesome icon.

To fix this, first I set the scope.tooltipIsOpen to true and as expected it displayed the tooltips by default.

Then I put some $log.info in the code to see if the value was updated to false. It seems that the value is updated. I also checked if the events were triggered and they are. I assume that the view doesn't update as it should so the tooltip remains displayed. I eventually tried to put a scope.$apply() in the post function, without success.

Here is my directive :

```
 app.directive('toClipboard',
    ['$log', 'ngClipboard',
    function ($log, ngClipboard) {
        function compile(element, attrs) {
            return {
                pre: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                   if (!attrs.tooltipPlacement) {
                        attrs.tooltipPlacement = 'auto top';
                    }
                },
                post: function (scope, element) {
                    scope.copy = ngClipboard.toClipboard;

                    // Tooltip hidden by default.
                   scope.tooltipIsOpen = false;

                    // Hiding tooltip.
                    element.on('mouseenter', function () {
                        scope.tooltipIsOpen = false;
                    });

                    // Hiding tooltip.
                    element.on('mouseleave', function () {
                        scope.tooltipIsOpen = false;
                    });
                }
            }
        }


        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                'clipboardData': '@',
                'tooltipPlacement': '@'
            },
            compile: compile,
            templateUrl: 'elements/_span-clipboard.html'
        };
    }
]);
```

NB: ngClipboard is a service to copy data to clipboard.

Here is the associated HTML template:

```
<span>
    <i class="fa fa-copy clickable"
       uib-tooltip="Copied"
       tooltip-placement="tooltipPlacement"
       tooltip-is-open="tooltipIsOpen"
       tooltip-trigger="'click'"
       ng-click="copy(clipboardData)"></i>
</span>
```

Do you have any idea or any lead to solve this issue ?

Thanking you in advance,

Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/okzxdSz1VvbkycehMT2G?p=preview

Comment: Hi Cybermate I see in your scope object that you only have `'clipboardData': '@','tooltipPlacement': '@'` try adding teh values you want with 2 way binding.

Comment: If I understand you want me to add 'tooltipIsOpen': '=' ? I will do it tomorrow as I am at home but I can try with a Plunker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this works by wrapping my code in $timeout();. Here is the working code:

```
app.directive('toClipboard',
    ['$log', '$timeout', 'ngClipboard',
        function ($log, $timeout, ngClipboard) {
            function compile(element, attrs) {
                return {
                    pre: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                        if (!attrs.iconClass) {
                            attrs.iconClass = 'fa-copy';
                        }

                        if (!attrs.iconColorClass) {
                            attrs.iconColorClass = 'text-primary';
                        }

                        if (!attrs.tooltipPlacement) {
                            attrs.tooltipPlacement = 'auto top';
                        }
                    },
                    post: function (scope, element) {
                        scope.copy = ngClipboard.toClipboard;

                        // Tooltips hidden by default.
                        scope.tooltipIsOpen = false;

                        // Hiding tooltips on mouseenter event.
                        element.on('mouseenter', function () {
                            $timeout(
                                function() {
                                    scope.tooltipIsOpen = false;
                                }, 200
                            );

                        });

                        // Hiding tooltips on mouseleave event.
                        element.on('mouseleave', function () {
                            $timeout(
                                function() {
                                    scope.tooltipIsOpen = false;
                                }, 200
                            );
                        });
                    }
                }
            }


            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                replace: true,
                scope: {
                    'iconClass': '@',
                    'iconColorClass': '@',
                    'clipboardData': '@',
                    'tooltipPlacement': '@'
                },
                compile: compile,
                templateUrl: 'elements/_span-clipboard.html'
            };
        }
    ]
);
```

$timeout makes sure it runs within an $apply cycle I guess.